# unlist a column with a list of dates in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I've been looking at using the unnest() function in tidyr for a column that has lists of dates.

```
x <- seq(from= as.POSIXct('2011-01-01 14:00:00'),length.out=100,by = "hour")

y <- seq(from= as.POSIXct('2012-01-01 14:00:00'),length.out=100,by = "hour")
df <- data.frame(x,y)
```

When I try to create a list for each row, and then unnest it. I get the following error.

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(sequence = list(seq.POSIXt(x,y,"10 min"))) %>% unnest(sequence)
```

> Error: Each column must either be a list of vectors or a list of data frames [sequence]

Can someone else help with this? I've done this with numbers, and the unnest function works fine. However, it doesn't seem to work with lists containing date/ datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coerce the result of `seq.POSIXt()` into a data frame and make a list of that...

```
x <- seq(from= as.POSIXct('2011-01-01 14:00:00'),length.out=100,by = "hour")
y <- seq(from= as.POSIXct('2012-01-01 14:00:00'),length.out=100,by = "hour")
df <- data.frame(x,y)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sequence = list(data.frame(seq.POSIXt(x, y, "10 min")))) %>% 
  unnest(sequence)

# # A tibble: 5,256,100 x 3
#    x                   y                   seq.POSIXt.x..y...10.min..
#    <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>                    
#  1 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2012-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-01 14:00:00       
#  2 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2012-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-01 14:10:00       
#  3 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2012-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-01 14:20:00       
#  4 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2012-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-01 14:30:00       
#  5 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2012-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-01 14:40:00       
#  6 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2012-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-01 14:50:00       
#  7 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2012-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-01 15:00:00       
#  8 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2012-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-01 15:10:00       
#  9 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2012-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-01 15:20:00       
# 10 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2012-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-01 15:30:00       
# # ... with 5,256,090 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to reproduce the error but thought an alternative approach might be helpful.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sequence = paste(seq.POSIXt(x, y, "10 min"), collapse=",")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  separate_rows(sequence, sep=",") %>%
  mutate(sequence = as.POSIXct(sequence))
```

OR

If you want to use `unnest` then

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sequence = list(seq.POSIXt(x, y, "10 min"))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  unnest(sequence)
```

**Output is:**

```
   x                   y                   sequence           
   <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-02 14:00:00 2011-01-01 14:00:00
 2 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-02 14:00:00 2011-01-01 14:10:00
 3 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-02 14:00:00 2011-01-01 14:20:00
 4 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-02 14:00:00 2011-01-01 14:30:00
 5 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-02 14:00:00 2011-01-01 14:40:00
...
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(x = structure(c(1293870600L, 1293874200L, 1293877800L, 
1293881400L, 1293885000L, 1293888600L, 1293892200L, 1293895800L, 
1293899400L, 1293903000L), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    y = structure(c(1293957000L, 1293960600L, 1293964200L, 1293967800L, 
    1293971400L, 1293975000L, 1293978600L, 1293982200L, 1293985800L, 
    1293989400L), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("x", 
"y"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks Prem. Can I ask what version of R were you using?

Comment: My current machine has `R version 3.4.0`

Comment: That is weird, I've got the same version and I still get the error. We were able to reproduce it on another machine in the office.

Comment: I'll test it at home to see if I can reproduce the error. BTW you may try to re-install `dplyr` and `tidyr` in your machine.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken `data.frame` doesn't support well list-column. 
Try to replace `df <- data.frame(x,y)` by `df <- tibble::tibble(x, y)`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
x <- seq(from= as.POSIXct('2011-01-01 14:00:00'),length.out=100,by = "hour")

y <- seq(from= as.POSIXct('2012-01-01 14:00:00'),length.out=100,by = "hour")
df <- tibble::tibble(x,y)


df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(sequence = list(seq.POSIXt(x,y,"10 min"))) %>% unnest(sequence)
#> # A tibble: 5,256,100 x 3
#>    x                   y                   sequence           
#>    <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
#>  1 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2012-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-01 14:00:00
#>  2 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2012-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-01 14:10:00
#>  3 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2012-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-01 14:20:00
#>  4 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2012-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-01 14:30:00
#>  5 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2012-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-01 14:40:00
#>  6 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2012-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-01 14:50:00
#>  7 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2012-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-01 15:00:00
#>  8 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2012-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-01 15:10:00
#>  9 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2012-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-01 15:20:00
#> 10 2011-01-01 14:00:00 2012-01-01 14:00:00 2011-01-01 15:30:00
#> # ... with 5,256,090 more rows
```

Comment: I've tried converting the dataframe to a tibble format. And I still seem to get the same error.

Comment: Weird, I also ran this code and got the same error as @theArun first posted

Comment: i'm using tidyr version 0.8.0.